# How to exchange dates from loop in to an array in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dataframe

I would like to ask how to exchange dates from loop in to an array in python?
I need an array of irregular, random dates with hours. So, I prepared a solution:

```
import datetime
import radar
r2 =()
for a in range(1,10):
       r2 = r2+(radar.random_datetime(start='1985-05-01', stop='1985-05-04'),)
r3 = list(r2)
print(r3)
```

As the result I get a list like:

```
[datetime.datetime(1985, 5, 3, 17, 59, 13), datetime.datetime(1985, 5, 2, 15, 58, 30), datetime.datetime(1985, 5, 2, 9, 46, 35), datetime.datetime(1985, 5, 3, 10, 5, 45), datetime.datetime(1985, 5, 2, 4, 34, 43), datetime.datetime(1985, 5, 3, 9, 52, 51), datetime.datetime(1985, 5, 2, 22, 7, 17), datetime.datetime(1985, 5, 1, 15, 28, 14), datetime.datetime(1985, 5, 3, 13, 33, 56)]
```

But I need strings in the list like:

```
list2 = ['1985-05-02 08:48:46','1985-05-02 10:47:56','1985-05-03 22:07:11', '1985-05-03 22:07:11','1985-05-01 03:23:43']
```

Comment: Convert it to a string like: `r2 = r2+(str(radar.random_datetime(start='1985-05-01', stop='1985-05-04')),)`

Comment: Its works! Thanks a lot, how can I award you?

Comment: You can accept the answer.  And if you hang for a while and get 15 reputation, you can start upvoting answers.

Comment: I will do it, Thanks :-). I will send award for this everybody after obtain 15 reputation. I promise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the datetime to a string with [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) like:

#### Code:

```
str(radar.random_datetime(start='1985-05-01', stop='1985-05-04'))
```

#### Test Code:

```
import radar

r2 = ()
for a in range(1, 10):
    r2 = r2 + (str(
        radar.random_datetime(start='1985-05-01', stop='1985-05-04')),)
r3 = list(r2)
print(r3)
```

#### Results:

```
['1985-05-01 21:06:29', '1985-05-01 04:43:11', '1985-05-02 13:51:03', 
 '1985-05-03 03:20:44', '1985-05-03 19:59:14', '1985-05-02 21:50:34', 
 '1985-05-01 04:13:50', '1985-05-03 23:28:36', '1985-05-02 15:56:23']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to convert the date generated by radar before adding it to the list.
e.g.

```
import datetime
import radar
r2 =()
for a in range(1,10):
 t=datetime.datetime(radar.random_datetime(start='1985-05-01', stop='1985-05-04'))
 r2 = r2+(t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),)
r3 = list(r2)
print(r3)
```

Comment: `strftime()` is great solution if you need a non-standard format.  The date format the OP desires is the standard format, so a simple `str()` can do that.  Also it is a good idea to format your answers so that the most important information is presented first. This allows subsequent readers to find the most important parts of your answer quickly.  Look at how I presented my answer for one way to do this. Cheers.

Comment: Infosys from Bubaneswar Orisa? I heve been there from Xavier MBA.

Comment: @WojciechMoszczyński I'm working in other Infosys Development Center, it is Mohali, India.